# Find text by search and highlight current result only

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, search, highlight

Trying to highlight current/single text only, like browser "Control-F" keyboard command search. find next/new text when search again is good. But it's highlight all result, trying to highlight only Current result/text.

**JS below:**

```
$('body').on('keydown', '#searchfor', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 32 &&  e.target.selectionStart === 0) {
      return false;
    }  
});

//Create some vars to later check for: 
//['text you are searching', 'number of highlights','actual highlight']
var searching,
    limitsearch,
    countsearch;

$('button#search').click(function() {
    var searchedText = $('#searchfor').val();
    var page = $('#ray-all_text');

    //Now check if the text on input is valid
    if (searchedText != "") {
        //If the actual text on the input is different from the prev search
        if(searching != searchedText) {
            page.find('span').contents().unwrap();
            var pageText = page.html();
            var theRegEx = new RegExp("(" + searchedText + ")", "igm");
            var newHtml = pageText.replace(theRegEx, "<span>$1</span>");
            page.html(newHtml);
            //Set your variables to the actual search
            searching = searchedText;
            limitsearch = page.find('span').length;
            countsearch=0;
        } else {
            //If it's the same of the prev search then move to next item instead of repaint html
            countsearch<limitsearch-1 ? countsearch++ : countsearch=0;
            console.log(countsearch+'---'+limitsearch)
        }
        //Go to target search
        $('body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#ray-all_text span").eq(countsearch).offset().top - 50}, 
        200);
     } else {
        alert('empty search')
     }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ray-search">
  <div class="field" id="ray-search-form">
    <input type="text" id="searchfor" placeholder="what are you searching for?" />
    <button type="button" id="search">Press to Find!</button>
  </div>
</div>

<article id="ray-all_text">
  <p>
    This manual and web site, all information and data and photos contained herein, are the s...
  </p>
</article>
```

Please check example: :https://jsfiddle.net/gaezs6s8/3/ 

There any solution?

Comment: You want to highlight only the **first** result?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: What you're searching for is [mark.js](https://markjs.io)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a class to the current target. The lines from your code I change:

```
var actual = $("#ray-all_text span").eq(countsearch);
$('.active').removeClass('active');
actual.addClass('active');
$('body').animate({
   scrollTop: actual.offset().top - 50}, 
200);
```

And on the CSS:

```
#ray-all_text span.active {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

## [Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gaezs6s8/6/)

Comment: hi, thanks, but first search is working, when search another text (second time) then it's not able to find: please check on my site: http://www.glass2.com/instruction-manual

Comment: when search another text (second time) then it's find "DRAWING EXAMPLE" (every time) not find exact text. check: http://www.glass2.com/instruction-manual

Comment: @Aariba you have this id `ray-all_text`duplicated ID's ust be unique, that can be breaking the JS